# Program is stuck in an infnite loop and can't figure out why

Tags: c

Just a simple program of take 10 integers and tell me which one the largest is. This is my first time working in C although I have programmed in Java, Python, and Ruby before. It will only enter an infinite loop if I enter a character instead of an integer. It sets the current variable to -8995460(or something like that) and then just repeats that ad infinitum. Am I just making a dumb mistake somewhere, or is this something that I don't understand about C?

```
int main(void)
{
    int counter = 0;
    int largest = 0;
    while (counter != 10) 
    { 
        int current;
        printf("%s", "Enter non-negative number: "); 
        scanf_s("%d", &current); 
        if ((current >= 0) && (isdigit(current)))
        {

            if (current > largest)
            {
                largest = current; 
            }
            counter++; 
        }
        else 
        {
            puts("Invalid number. Number must be positive. \n");
        }

    }
    printf("%d", largest);
}
```

Comment: Did you check the value returned by `scanf`?  Why do you think `current` contains valid data?

Comment: Until you write the **ASCII code** of 10 digits...

Comment: @WilliamPursell yes I said in the description it returns a very large negative value(-8995460)

Comment: Yes, and that's perfectly reasonable.  Why do you think it is not?  If you check the value returned by scanf, this may make more sense.  (hint; scanf is very likely not changing the value of `current` at all)

Comment: Try initializing `current`, or print its value before the call to `scanf`.

Comment: hmm you are right it is not changing current at all. However, it is still going in a loop if I don't initialize that, why does scanf still have a value in it, and better yet, how would I go about removing the value in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As @SomeProgrammerDude pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46102958/14660), `isdigit` checks if a character is a digit. You're passing it an integer. It will interpret that integer as a character, so it will think `10` is a newline and `43` is a `+`. If you give it `50` it will pass because that's character `2`.

To check that `scanf` got an integer, don't check `current` because that will contain garbage if `scanf` failed. Instead, check the return value of `scanf` which tells you how many items it matched.

```
int counter = 0;
int largest = 0;

// It's safer to check for X < BOUND than X != BOUND in case
// X happens to go over the BOUND.
while (counter < 10) { 
    int current;
    printf("%s", "Enter non-negative number: ");

    // What if `scanf` didn't get a number?
    if( scanf("%d", &current) != 1 ) {
        puts("That doesn't look like a number");
    }
    // What if it isn't positive?
    else if( current < 0 ) {
        puts("Invalid number. Number must be positive. \n");
    }
    // Now that all the error conditions have been checked...
    else {
        if (current > largest)
        {
            largest = current; 
        }
        counter++; 
    }
}
printf("%d", largest);
```

But there's still a problem. If you get an invalid number, the code will go into an infinite loop. This is one of the [many, many, many problems with `scanf`](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html) in particular [this one](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfjam.html).

The problem is that `scanf` does not read lines, it reads as much as you tell it to. If it fails to read that much, it just leaves it on the buffer. If `scanf` fails it will leave the input on `stdin`. When you go to read again, you'll read the same input and fail again. If there's any extra input on the line, like `10 foo` it will read the `10` and then leave `foo` on the buffer to be read by the next call to `scanf`.

The general solution is to read input line by line and parse the line. Use `fgets` to read the line and `sscanf` to scan the string.

```
int counter = 0;
int largest = 0;
char line[255];
while (counter < 10) {
    int current;

    printf("%s", "Enter non-negative number: ");
    fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);

    if( sscanf(line, "%d", &current) != 1 ) {
        puts("That doesn't look like a number");
    }
    ...and the rest is the same...
}
```

This guarantees you'll never get into an infinite loop. Though if the input is larger than `line` it might have to loop through `fgets` several times to get all the input.

Comment: that's...annoying haha. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: @Andrew You're welcome. `scanf` is just one of many tempting but subtly dangerous standard C functions.

Answer (score 3):

You read an *integer* not a character. The [`isdigit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isdigit) checks if a *character* is a digit. If `current` is a single-digit number then it is, by virtue of being a single-digit number, definitely a "digit".

Because of this, the `isdigit` function will always return `0` (unless you enter a decimal value that correspond the the current character-encoding values for digits), which is equal to false in C, so you never increase `counter`.

For your problem I would use the `"%u"` format to `scanf` to read an unsigned decimal number, and check what [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) returns to see if the input was correct or not.

Note that if the input is not correct, it will be left in the input buffer for the next call to `scanf`, unless you remove it. The only portable way to remove it is to read character by character until you have read a newline.

Comment: okay, but I still get the same issue when I remove isdigit. O I didn't know it would leave it in the input buffer. So I need remove the incorrect thing from scanf. thanks

Answer (score 1):

isdigit() is used to check whether a character's ASCII code is the
       equivalent ASCII code of a number from 0-9. You should use it only
       with a character variable.

scanf("%d",&current) will always read an integer to the variable current. You need not check it. If you
   enter a character in the input you get an infinite loop since scanf()
   cannot store the character in any variable i.e. it is not getting what it is expecting.

You can get around the infinite loop problem by writing 
scanf("%s",&str) where str is a character array(string) instead of scanf_s("%d", &current). 
Now you can check whether the first character i.e. isdigit(str[0]).
If not a number skip it else
convert it to a number using atoi() function.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define BUF_LEN 256
int main()
{
    int counter = 0;
    int largest = 0;
    while (counter != 10) 
    { 
        char str[BUF_LEN];
        printf("%s", "Enter non-negative number: "); 
        scanf("%s", str); 
        if (isdigit(str[0]))//If first character is a digit then we asume that str contains a valid number. You should actually check it for all the characters in the string.
        {
            int current = atoi(str);//Convert string to integer (ASCII to Integer).
            if (current > largest)
            {
                largest = current; 
            }
            counter++; 
        }
        else 
        {
        puts("Invalid number. Number must be positive. \n");
        }

    }
    printf("%d", largest);
}
```